# Get the name of a value from an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

here is a sample the array I have

```
Array ( [57] => 0 [58] => 0 [59] => 0 [60] => 0 [61] => 0 [62] => 0 [63] => 0
```

The value names are randomly generated I want to get the name of each pair out of the array and the value I can get the value using

```
foreach ($_POST as $songvalue) {
print $songvalue;
```

}

But how do I get the name of the value

Comment: you mean array index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, with :

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$songvalue) {
    print $key;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
 //do thingies. $key is your key name
}
```

You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach($_POST as $key => $value)